# Provisonal Patent Cover Sheet Questions

Tags: provisional-application, provisional

1. I have noticed that the people creating the provisional patent would capitalize the title of the invention on their patent document. So, I have done that too. Should I capitalize the title in the Provisonal Patent Cover Sheet or write it normally.
2. Should I add the drawings in the same PDF document with my patent document or should the drawings be separate from the PDF document?
3. If it is possible to add those in one PDF document, how will they be counted? I mean on ENCLOSED APPLICATION PARTS section of the sheet, it says Drawing(s) Number of Sheets, and Specification Number of pages. Should the number of drawings be included in the number of specification pages? How do I calculate it.
4. Is the specification the PDF patent document with the field, background, summary, description of drawings, and detailed description of the invention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Capitalisation doesn't matter, it's purely a matter of style. Choose whatever you want.
2. Typically the same PDF document (though I may be wrong, as it's been a long time since I've done the actual filing myself).
3. The number of drawing sheets would be the number of pages in the PDF document that contain drawings. The number of specification pages would be the number of pages in the PDF document that contain text.
4. Yes, and the claims (if you have any).